# How to combine Facebook pages

Tags: facebook

I have 3 Facebook pages having different fans. I would like to combine all pages with fans. Is it possible? If no, how can I add all fans to a single page?

Answer (score 3):

There's no real way to do this.  According to their Help Ceneter:  http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=13589

> **I have two accounts. Is it possible to
>   merge them?** Facebook does not allow
>   you to merge accounts. You need to
>   copy your profile content (e.g.
>   photos, notes, etc.) and add it
>   manually to your more active account.
>   Unfortunately, there will be some
>   things you cannot transfer, such as
>   Friends and Wall posts. Once you have
>   moved all information onto a single
>   account, please deactivate your old
>   account from the Settings tab of the
>   Account page. Afterward, you can add
>   email addresses and networks to your
>   new account from the Account page.
>   Please note that maintaining multiple
>   accounts is a violation of Facebook's
>   Terms of Use.

Comment: So the same rule for *profile accounts* applies to *fan pages* ?

Comment: Yes, the same rule applies.  It's a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to invite the fans into the new page you wish to establish as the master page. All fans arrive on a page through their own action and effort, and you'll have to persuade everybody to participate in joining the new desired page. One method of persuasion is to regularly re-announce the eventual and future demise of the pages you desire to extinguish in this merger process.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a video of how to merge two Facebook pages here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s80swkoDpN8&list=UUCcJDbhnWxoUG8W5olPei-g&index=1&feature=plcp
Hope it helps!